# Mostrar datos de una matriz

Tags: java, matrices, netbeans-8.2

necesito ayuda para mostrar los datos de una matriz, utilizo una variable a, que indica el numero de registros(columnas) que tendrá y el 4 son las filas o los campos que contiene(identificacion, nombre, direccion, telefono), el problema que tengo es que necesito ingresar unicamente la identificacion y mostrar el resto de datos que existen en esa fila.

```
    int a;
    a=Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText());
    String datos[][] = new String[a][4];

    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ha ingresado "+i+" datos");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ingrese los datos en el siguiente orden \nCedula\nNombre\nDireccion\nTelefono");
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            datos[i][j]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese los datos");
        }

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Busqueda de los datos ingresados");
```

Answer (score 0):

Si desea buscar solo la identificación , debería hacerlo en la posición 0 de cada iteración. *(código comentado)*

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Busqueda de los datos ingresados");
//Ingresamos el código cedula a buscar
String code = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese cédula a buscar");
int pos= -1; // Var temporal
//Iteramos el array
for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
    // Sí en la fila i , la posición fija 0 porque 
    // es donde se guarda la cédula
    if(datos[i][0].equals(code)){
        //asignamos la posición de la fila
        pos = i;
        // cortamos el ciclo
        break;
    }   
}
//si es diferente , quiere decir que si lo encontró
if(pos!= -1){
    // Imprimimos el array , podría hacerlo campo por campo con datos[pos][0]
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Arrays.toString(datos[pos]));
}else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No existe el Usuario con ese Número de Cédula");
}
```

Sí utiliza *Java8* , haciendo uso de la clase [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) y de los `streams` podríamos lograr este objetivo. filtrando el array *(filter)* usando `lambdas` , con la condición `identificador.equals(x[0])` haciendo referencia al primer campo del `array`. Sí encuentra elemento `isPresent()` devolverá true y `optional.get()` obtendrá el array que cumplió con la condición.

```
Optional<String[]> optional = Arrays.stream(datos)
                               .filter(x -> identificador.equals(x[0]))
                               .findFirst();
if(optional.isPresent()) {
    String[] data = optional.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Campo : " + (i)+ data[i]);
    }
}else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se encuentra el Identificador " + identificador);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, no entiendo bien como estas intentado poner los datos en la matriz ya que en tu descripción decis que cada registro va en un columna y cada fila es un campo, sin embargo en el código estás poniendo cada registro como fila y que las columnas sean cada campo.

Ahora para mostrar un registro a partir de su identificación basta con realizar una búsqueda en la primera columna de la matriz de ese identificador:

```
String identificador = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese identificador");
boolean encontrado = false; //Hago uso de una bandera para cortar el while
int pos = 0;

while(!encontrado && pos < a){
    //Pregunto si la cadena de esa posicion es igual a identificador
    if(identificador.equals(datos[pos][0]))
        encontrado = true;   //Encontré la fila
    else
        pos++;
}

//Si la posición es válida
if(pos < a){
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, datos[pos][j]);
}
else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El identificador ingresado no existe");
}
```